# How can i hide all the text before "-" dash?

Tags: html, css, arrays

**There is a paragraph in the div class container, how can i hide the text before "-"? **

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor - incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can try to do it with Js, the moment when the document load, you could remove it

Comment: permanently? Hidden or removed? have you made an attempt?

Comment: i want to display:none the text before dash "-" @depperm

Comment: What if there are multiple dashes? What do you expect the outcome to be?

Comment: are you loading the content dynamically or you want to do this on a button click or something?

Comment: add a <pre></pre> tag around the text you want to hide and add css to hide it display:none and you can later controll the behaviour of that part

Comment: @Terry Yes for multiple dashes , display none of all the text before dashes

Comment: @Soothran Dynamically

Answer (score 1):

in js

```
var element = document.querySelector('.container p')
if(element){
    element.innerText = element.innerText.replace(/.*- /, '');
    // if you need non greedy regexp use /.*?- / instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the content before - in a span.

and then apply display: none to span.

```
span{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide when, show again when? Take up space or not?

CSS

```css
.hide { color:white }
span:hover { color:black }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p><span class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor </span>- incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Plain JS

```js
var container = document.querySelector("div>p");
var text = container.innerText;
container.innerHTML =  '<span class="hide">'+text.substring(0,text.indexOf("-"))+'</span>'+
  text.substring(text.indexOf("-"))

container.addEventListener("mouseover",function() { this.querySelector("span").classList.toggle("hide")});
```

```css
.hide { color:white }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor - incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to hide this text dynamically in which case you will need javascript, otherwise as Nitin implied you could just insert a `<span class="hidden">` manually into your text?

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const txt = container.querySelector('p').innerHTML.split('-')
const newMarkup = `<span class="hidden">${txt[0]}</span> ${txt[1]}`
container.innerHTML = newMarkup
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor - incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```